# SP 2010 Workflow Collect Data from CURRENT User

Tags: 2010, workflow, workflow-activity

I'm working with SharePoint 2010 workflows. I need to collect data from the current user then send an email. Specifically, I need to collect the email address of the recipient of the email.

What is the keyword/mechanism for saying current user in SP '10 OOB workflows?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for Workflow Context:Current User? On the collect data from user, click this user and select Workflow Lookup for a user and then set Workflow Context and Current User, unless this is triggered off an item create/change then you could use the Current Item Created By or Modified By from that window instead.